Determine the number of surjective functions
Determine the number of surjective functions $f:A→B$, where $A=$ {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} $B=$ {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, and $X=$ {1,2,3} $⊂A$, $Y=$ {1,2,3} $⊂B$, such that $f(X)=Y$

Please edit to show your efforts.  Note that the only way $f$ could be surjective is if there is exactly one value in $B$ that is hit twice, and all the others hit once.  That helps with the count considerably.

Check out the page https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/444923 for advice on asking a good question. E.g., note "The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title." Also, it's recommended in the 'pare down your question' part to remove irrelevant parts about whether or not you'll fail the class etc.

You might find this useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2955328/how-many-surjective-functions-from-a-1-2-3-4-to-b-a-b-c-when-4?noredirect=1
